# Cockpit Software Updates - Loading available updates failed - Cannot refresh cache whilst offline

Tags: networking, server, netplan, cockpit

On a Ubuntu Server LTS 20.x, with renderer : networkd, LAN / WAN Connectivity
are all properly fucntional. However in Cockpit > Software Updates, it gives the error message:

```
Loading available updates failed    
Cannot refresh cache whilst offline
```

Changing the setting to
renderer : NetworkManager
makes Cockpit > Software Updates work flawlessly
without impacting the Networking module in Cockpit.

But I would rather stick to renderer : networkd
as this is a Server.

Any insight to get renderer : networkd to work ?
Or Cockpit just 'needs' NetworkManager ?

Note:

```
sudo systemctl stop network-manager.service    
sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service
```

Will make the Networking module in cockpit fail with
error :

```
Network devices and graphs require NetworkManager
```

Comment: Seems that is simply how the software works. https://dannyda.com/2020/04/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-server-19-cockpit-cannot-refresh-cache-whilst-offline-and-cannot-refresh-cache-whilst-offline-errors/

Comment: @David - disabling network-manager.service as advocated by that article disables the Networking module of Cockpit and gives error message -> Network devices and graphs require NetworkManager

Comment: I should have been more clear there is no good way to do what you want to do. They are all bad ways. That is an example of another bad way.

Comment: @David - Hehehehee .... I understand where you are coming from buddy ....

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Cockpit just 'needs' Network Manager.

That was hinted at in my question as well.

Changing the setting to **renderer : NetworkManager**
makes **Cockpit > Software Updates** work flawlessly
**without** impacting the **Networking** module in Cockpit.

Other workarounds cause some modules ( especially the Networking module ) to not function properly. **Cockpit project github reference** -> https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/issues/15746

Note : This method also ensures that when you use Cockpit to manage your Virtual Machines, creating bridges etc work **flawlessly** as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/issues/8477), the easiest workaround until Ubuntu settles on a network manager is this:

```
nmcli con add type dummy con-name fake ifname fake0 ip4 1.2.3.4/24 gw4 1.2.3.1
```

Comment: Would just accepting NetworkManager ( nm )  as the default renderer  be better than creating a dummy interface using the NetworkManager (nm  ->  nmcli   ) ? For me, i just wanted consistency in the entire chain. I am just committed to nmcli now as its just very capable and well documented. The cockpit team also feels that this issue is NOT a bug for them, hence my decision to stick to NM

Comment: Is there anything beyond that command required? I ran it and it still does not work. https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/issues/8477#issuecomment-841398337

Comment: @JellyFilledNuts A reboot might help. I can use Discover to update Code after adding the fake network so it doesn't mistakenly think it's offline.